# Endless ssh attempt from my IP using my public key ? Fail2ban fail to log anything useful

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security

Lately, my hostinger server has been acting strange, I have hard time accessing the site hosted on it, I can't even ssh, however when I restart the server from hostinger panel. It works again.

Upon checking `top`, there was sshd process hogging 100% cpu, then I decided to view `/var/log/auth.log`.

[image]

Above gif image is my output of `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log`, up until now it still run endlessly without any break, the output appear to be accepted login log from my IP— and then disconnect (as in disconnect from ssh), and then reconnect again, and disconnect. I've been sitting here for 30 minute and it still spouting same thing.

Any clue of what might this be ? Is this actually an breach attempt ? I have setup fail2ban and ufw on this server, fail2ban logs doesn't yield any strange line.

`top` yield this.

[image]

Comment: When you say "from my IP", do you mean the server's IP, or your client/admin computer, or what? Whatever it is, have you checked that computer to see if something's running `ssh` and if so what/why?

Comment: I meant my own computer, which have public key authentication setup. I already checked there aren't any idle ssh running, but what's odd is even when I quit the ssh session, the server still uses 100% cpu and 100% ram (I can see this from hostinger panel, they have cpu and mem graph). What might be the problem?

Comment: Turn your computer off and investigate using another computer. If the problem stops then it's on the inactive computer. If it doesn't stop then some other computer uses some key that gets accepted. [Edit] the question and add what you found out.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sorry I just got back from long trip, upon seeing your comment I just realized my Pi's have access to all my server, it is configured to take backup daily at night. I might have to check onto that.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Your guess was spot on, I identified the issue coming from Raspbery Pi, apparently the script which backup my server file has failed, thus creating unlimited connection via ssh. If you can make your comment into answer, Ill gladly offer my bounty to you.

Comment: @Liso Nah. This was a guess and if you didn't forget about the Pi, you would check this out by yourself. I have all the reputation I need. Somewhat I would feel weird if I earned +50 from all this. Recently I wrote few *educative* answers about SSH and earned less. My comment required no special knowledge. It could turn out the problem was on your computer, then the comment would not be enough. So it's by chance: I was lucky to guess first and I was lucky it was all you needed. You post an answer. Please don't mention me in the answer, keep it technical. The bounty won't be refunded though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of this mess, I managed to catch the culprit, it is actually my Pi's who caused this whole thing to begin with— that also explain why `auth.log` showing login from my IP, and to top it off, it is using public key authentication (I only allow pubkey auth for my trusted device).

How did I find out about this ? The comment from @Kamil Maciorowski shed some light to my finding, so I try turning off the Pi and then my server would ran smoothly again— with no bizarre cpu usage.

I checked on my Pi and found the offending script, specifically following line.

```
rsync --remove-source-files -e "ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60" -chaP --stats --info=progress2 $host:/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") $backup_location/$host
```

As you can see I'm using `$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")` which return today date in *yyyy-mm-dd* format, the problem is I have append `hh:mm` to my backup directory— **BUT** have not changed the script to handle new naming format.

[image]
<sub>I changed the naming at November 12th</sub>

My suspicions were confirmed after I take a look at my rsync log, it clearly shows that it tried to `rsync` a nonexistant directory— over and over.

```
sent 8 bytes  received 115 bytes  14.47 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
+ [[ 5 -lt 5 ]]
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ fail '2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.'
+ echo 2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
+ true
+ rsync --remove-source-files -e 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60' -chaP --stats --info=progress2 vps-strat:/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13 /media/pi/local_backup/db-server/vps-strat
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Number of files: 0
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 115
Total bytes sent: 8
Total bytes received: 115

sent 8 bytes  received 115 bytes  12.95 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
+ [[ 5 -lt 5 ]]
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ fail '2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.'
+ echo 2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
+ true
+ rsync --remove-source-files -e 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60' -chaP --stats --info=progress2 vps-strat:/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13 /media/pi/local_backup/db-server/vps-strat
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Number of files: 0
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 115
Total bytes sent: 8
Total bytes received: 115

sent 8 bytes  received 115 bytes  16.40 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
+ [[ 5 -lt 5 ]]
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ fail '2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.'
+ echo 2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
+ true
+ rsync --remove-source-files -e 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60' -chaP --stats --info=progress2 vps-strat:/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13 /media/pi/local_backup/db-server/vps-strat
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Number of files: 0
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 115
Total bytes sent: 8
Total bytes received: 115

sent 8 bytes  received 115 bytes  12.95 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [Receiver=3.1.1]
rsync: [Receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
+ [[ 5 -lt 5 ]]
++ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
+ fail '2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.'
+ echo 2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
2021-11-13 03:43 // The command has failed after 5 attempts for vps-strat.
+ true
+ rsync --remove-source-files -e 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60' -chaP --stats --info=progress2 vps-strat:/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13 /media/pi/local_backup/db-server/vps-strat
receiving incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/user/mybackup/dbonly/2021-11-13" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have changed the script to match new naming, and no problem so far.

Bottom line, this is probably me being careless again, but I'm glad its not something sinister.

Answer (score 1):

By default `sshd` doesn't log wrong attempts of public keys (you'd need to increase its log level to enable them (it requires `LogLevel VERBOSE` in `sshd_config`)...

Or you can simply switch to `aggressive` mode in an jail of fail2ban - set the mode for `sshd` jail in your `jail.local`:

```
[sshd]
mode = aggressive
enabled = true
```

Hereafter fail2ban would also consider not authenticated attempts (bots, port-scanner, etc connecting to sshd-listener) and ban such evildoers.

To see the difference you can compare the output of these 2 commands:

```
?sudo? fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/auth.log sshd
?sudo? fail2ban-regex -v /var/log/auth.log 'sshd[mode=aggressive]'
```